# Why does ASP.NET Core Tag Helper for Boolean Checkbox Not Display Label?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm looking at the login.cshtml page of a new asp.net core account view page and I notice that the use DisplayNameFor to output the name of the field ("RememberMe").  Why is the  not sufficent for this?  It seems the label is not participating.

```
<div class="checkbox">
 <label asp-for="RememberMe">
    <input asp-for="RememberMe" />
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.RememberMe)
 </label>
</div>
```

Since input and label are both Tag Helpers, shouldn't the name be rendered automatically like for email and other input tags on same page?

Comment: Doesn't seem right to me. Either you use Label with the text + input box as child elements WITHOUT a `for` attribute or you have label and input on the same level (children of div) and then use `for` on the label. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very interesting question.

Per MVC [code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/LabelTagHelper.cs#L81), the `labeltaghelper` gives precedence to available child content. Only when no child content is available will it put in a default label text (order and possible values [per](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/649ee4d28d7cf46401c09ad0108a4f23b6d7d513/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewFeatures/DefaultHtmlGenerator.cs#L431))

If you remove all child elements of the label you will notice that the label will in fact use the display name or property name (Remember Me)

Personally, I think in the template, it's just a design decision to use `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.RememberMe)`so that it goes well with bootstrap.

**Update:** This would show the same information but the formatting is not going to be as good

```
<div class="checkbox">
<input asp-for="RememberMe" />
 <label asp-for="RememberMe">
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: When I remove "@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.RememberMe)", no "remember me" shows up. What would the cshtml file look like to have "remember me" show up on the page.

Comment: @PeterKellner updated the answer to show a simple example. Hope that helps.